# Is there a way to spy on parameters passed to a Mocked object in Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, verify

I have a service that I am mocking using Mockito. Is there any way that I can verify the parameters passed to the service call?

For example:

I have a service named `employeeAnalyzer.calculateAnnualAppraisalForEmployee(Employee emp)`.

So from unit test I would like to do something like

```
verifyThat ("John", emp.getName());
verifyThat ("Doe", emp.getLastName);
```

Basically I want to spy on the parameter that was sent to the service which I inject using

```
@InjectMocks
EmployeeAnalyzer employeeAnalyzer;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Definitely! Mockito is awesome. You can use an [ArgumentCaptor](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.13/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) to capture the `Employee` parameter and then do some assertions.

(example taken from the previous link)

```java
ArgumentCaptor<Person> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Person.class);
verify(mock).doSomething(argument.capture());
assertEquals("John", argument.getValue().getName());
```

Or the new funky way using the [@Captor](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Captor.html) annotation

```java
@Captor ArgumentCaptor<AsyncCallback<Foo>> captor;

@Before
public void init(){
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test public void shouldDoSomethingUseful() {
   //...
   verify(mock).doStuff(captor.capture());
   assertEquals("foo", captor.getValue());
}
```

Comment: is something similar possible for parameters using `when()` ? Maybe the class `Employee` is ridiculous to create and I'm only interested in some properties?

Comment: For testing, I recomend using the [Test Data Builder](http://natpryce.com/articles/000714.html) pattern. Makes it easy to create templated objects that you can later tailor in your tests. And if a class is too difficult to build, it screams that there's a problem with the design. As a rule of thumb is a bad idea to mock entities and value objects.